# Why android notifications are not occurring after every 2 mins?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-notifications, development-environment

I am trying to create a notification after every 2 mins but , only single notification is getting created(when app is started).
My code is :

notifyme.java :

```
public class notifyme extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();

    Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder=TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent=stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notify=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Hello")
            .setContentText("Some random text")
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManager nMgr=(NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(this.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Random r=new Random();
    int nid=r.nextInt(50000)+1;
    nMgr.notify(nid,notify.build());
}





@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

In MainActivity.java :

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, notifyme.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent =       PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent,0);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.cancel(contentIntent);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),120*1000, contentIntent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you don't need a whole service to show a notification, if that's all it's doing, you could use a `BroadcastReceiver` and use `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` method. BroadcastReceiver needs less memory and doesn't have any life-cycle (which could complicate things).

The reason you're not seeing more than one notification is on the line `nMgr.notify(119,notify.build());`

This number `119` is the notification ID. So after X seconds that it's executing that code again, your new notification is directly replacing the old one and it all looks as if it hasn't changed.

If you want to put several notifications up (AKA. SPAM the user), you should always change that number. maybe using a `Random`

Comment: Change it to 'BroadcastReceiver' then. Your service is created by the first one and never destroyed, so it won't go trough create again

Comment: BroadcastReceiver did the trick.Even when same notification id is provided, it still gives the notification sound if previous notification is not cleared else it creates one (as required). Thank You

Answer (score 0):

First of all, making new notifications in every two seconds is completely against guidelines.

As [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/managing.html) says :

> When you need to issue a notification multiple times for the same type
>   of event, you should avoid making a completely new notification.
>   Instead, you should consider updating a previous notification, either
>   by changing some of its values or by adding to it, or both.

here the issue is that you are using the same ID to create the notification. (here 19).

When you publish a notification, if there is an active notification with the same id. notificatipon manager will update the existing one. So everytime the service is running, it just updates the notification with id "19".

If you are keen on issuing notifications on every 2 minutes (Which will affect the user-experience of your app very badly, let me warn you), try giving different ids to the notifications. You can save the issued ids in SharedPreferences or something.